# I have many large folders of photos on Google Drive. How can I move them into Google Photos?

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

I've been backing up old photos to Google Drive for a couple of years, and I only just recently found out how amazing Google Photos is (automatically organizes photos, builds albums and animations, etc.).

I'd like to import all of my Google Drive photos into the Google Photos app.

What's the best way to go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2):

I did this fairly recently. If you want to make use of the unlimited free storage Google provides for "high quality" photos (meaning that they have been auto resized to 16 megapixels), the you can't import them from Google drive, they need to be downloaded and uploaded again

1. Install the Google Drive desktop app and sync the photo folders to your disk.
2. Install the Google Photos [Desktop Uploader](https://photos.google.com/apps) app, and set it running uploading and resizing.
3. Leave your PC overnight.
4. Once you're satisfied that they exist in both places you can delete the drive copy.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com)
2. Go to the [Settings](https://photos.google.com/settings) (hamburger menu, click "Settings"
3. Turn on the "Google Drive" option

   > Google Drive
   > Show Google Drive photos & videos in your Photos library

It may take some time to sync, but you should start seeing the images you have in Google Drive show up in Google Photos.

(This solution is probably mutually exclusive of [this solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/85475/354))

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com)
2. Go to "Settings" (Gear menu | Settings)
3. On the "General" tab, turn on the *Create a Google Photos folder* option; this creates a "Google Photos" folder within Google Drive which holds copies of all of your photos in your photo library
4. Move the photos in Google Drive you want to see in your library somewhere under the "Google Photos" directory.

(This solution is probably mutually exclusive of [this solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/85474/354))